# Android ListView with a Spinner in each row doesn't fire OnItemSelected

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-listview, spinner

I have a Layout in Android which has a ListView which then inflates another layout as its rows using an adapter, pretty standard.

The row layout which is inflated X times depending on how many rows there needs to be contains a spinner. I add a seSelectedItemListener to the Spinner yet when the Spinner is pressed, the options are displayed, then an item is pressed/selected, then the OnItemSelectedListener constructor is fired yet the overrided onItemSelected is not. If i inflate the row layout seprately not in a List View and select an item in the Spinner then the onSelectedItem fires...

Any ideas why this happens or how/if it can work this way?

OnItemSelected class:

```
class SelectedSizeChangeListener implements OnItemSelectedListener {
    Spinner product_size;
    TextView product_sell_price;
    TextView product_cost_price;
    Drink item;
    Drink_Size drink_size;
    SelectedSizeChangeListener()
    {
        String s = "here1";
    }
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
        View view, int pos, long id) {

        String s = "here2";
    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView parent) {

        String s = "here3";
    }
}
```

Adding the onItemSelected class to the spinner:

```
product_size_spinner.post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                product_size_spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new SelectedSizeChangeListener());
            }
        });
```

Any help would be great!

Adrian

Comment: What was the logcat output??

Comment: are you using a custom listview ?

Answer (score 0):

Try

`android:focusable="false"
  android:focusableInTouchMode="false"` 
in list view

**Pro-tip:**

try to use [PopUpMenu](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#PopupMenu) rather than Spinner.

Example [android-popupwindow in list View](http://rajeshandroiddeveloper.blogspot.in/2013/07/android-popupwindow-example-in-listview.html)